# Merging of 2 custom List objects in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list

Can someone help me out or can give me any pointer of solving this particular issue. Merging of list objects, by comparing 2 List of objects.

It is manageable with simple for loops and linq, as data is huge I was searching for optimum way or any algorithm for this purpose would be of great help.

```
class user
{
    string userID;
    string userName;
    //...
    List<role> objRoles;
}
class role
{
    List<pemission> objPermisison;
}
class pemission
{ 
    bool newlyAdded;
    //...
}

List<User> List1 :

User1      
 - Role_1
     - Permission_1 
     - Permission_2 
 - Role_2
     - Permission_3
     - Permission_4 


List<User> List2 :

User1      
 - Role_1
     - Permission_3  
     - Permission_4 
 - Role_2
     - Permission_5
     - Permission_4 


Required Result : 

List<User> Resultant_List :

User1      
 - Role_1
     - Permission_1 
     - Permission_2 
     - Permission_3 - Flag (Newly Added)
     - Permission_4 - Flag (Newly Added)
 - Role_2
     - Permission_3
     - Permission_4 
     - Permission_5  - Flag (Newly Added)
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Simple `for` loop will merge two lists for `O(N)`, where `N` is the minimum of their lengths. There is no more "optimum" way to do this. Linear is the best option.

Comment: The only better way is to avoid using two lists and use one.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of an existing data structure in C#/Vb.Net, ... code ? You must start with that. Then Stack overflow users can show you what is achievable

Comment: Emmanuel, there no existing data structure implemented for this, currently i am implementing using for each loop, looping to all the users, then its inner loop then its inner loop, and populating the same object in a temp variable once one user is verified I am adding that in a new resultant list, this is under implementation. So just thought of whether i can get any optimum way or proven methods from stackoverflow folks.

Comment: @Jack This question already has two close votes, one more and it gets closed... show some work and explain better!

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2012/10/18/merge-collections-without-duplicates-in-c) to merge two lists without duplicates, a dictionary merge is the fastest method...

"This solution converts list2 to a dictionary and then it loops a single time over list1. It either adds to the dictionary or replaces the value of list2 if it was a duplicate. This seemed to be a much more efficient algorithm."

```
var dict = list2.ToDictionary(p => p.userID);

foreach (var person in list1)
{
    dict[person.userID] = person;
}

var merged = dict.Values.ToList();
```